# Strange special character encoding error

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, base64, special-characters

I have a very strange character encoding error:
I am sending a textfield to a script via jQuerys ajax function.
Assuming I want to send the euro sign

> echo $string;

produces

> €

however

> echo base64_decode(base64_encode($string));

produces

> â‚¬

any hints on how I could debug this problem?

Comment: This is not a real world example though, is it? You are encoding it in one page, and decoding it in another, aren't you? In that case, you need to tell us which character set those pages use.

Comment: I don't believe you. base64_decode(base64_encode($string)) should give alays $string back.

Comment: there must be some issue with charset, i don't remember exactly

Comment: Well, in UTF-8 "€" is represented as "e282ac", and "â‚¬" is represented as "e23fac" in ISO-8859-15. So, you're changing changing the data somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is not a real world example though, is it? You are encoding it in one page, and decoding it in another, aren't you? In that case, you need to tell us which character set those pages use.

Pekka was right, my charsets got mixed up, after I set a global UTF8 charset header, everything works fine.